# How to validate related models for user registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper, fluentvalidation

In ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project, I am implementing Fluent Validation, Entity Framework and `IdentityDbContext`.

I have these model classes:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public string AppUserId { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
}
```

`AppUser` and `Customer` have a one-to-one relationship.

I also have this DTO:

```
public class RegisterUserDto
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Then I am using Fluent Validation:

```
public class RegisterUserDtoValidator : AbstractValidator<RegisterUserDto>
{
    public RegisterUserDtoValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(user => user.UserName).NotNull();
        RuleFor(user => user.FirstName).HumanName();
        RuleFor(user => user.LastName).HumanName();
        RuleFor(user => user.PhoneNumber).PhoneNumber();
        RuleFor(user => user.Email).EmailAddress();
        RuleFor(user => user.Password).Password();
        RuleFor(user => user.Address).NotNull();
        RuleFor(user => user.State).NotNull();
    }
}
```

**AutoMapping:**

```
public class MapInitializer : Profile
{
    public MapInitializer ()
    {
        // Authentication Maps
        CreateMap<AppUser, RegisterUserDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Customer, RegisterUserDto>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Dependency injection:

```
public static class DIServiceExtension
{
    public static void AddDependencyInjection (this IServiceCollection services)
    {
       services.AddTransient<IValidator<RegisterUserDto>, RegisterUserDtoValidator>();
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.ConfigureAutoMappers();

builder.Services.AddDependencyInjection();

builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddFluentValidation(options =>
    {
        options.AutomaticValidationEnabled = false;
        options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    });
```

Then finally the `AuthService`:

```
public async Task<Response<string>> Register(RegisterUserDto model)
{
    var user = _mapper.Map<AppUser>(model);
    var response = new Response<string>();

    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
    {
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, UserRoles.Customer);

            var customer = new Customer
            {
                AppUserId = user.Id,
                Address = model.Address,
                State = model.State
            };

            await _unitOfWork.Customers.InsertAsync(customer);
            await _unitOfWork.Save();

            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
            response.Succeeded = true;
            response.Data = user.Id;
            response.Message = "User created successfully!";

            transaction.Complete();

            return response;
        }

        response.Message = GetErrors(result);
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        response.Succeeded = false;
        transaction.Complete();

        return response;
    };
}
```

**Note:** `Address` and `State` are to be inserted into the `Customer` table.

As shown above, I am inserting data into both `AppUser` and `Customer`.

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("register")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Response<string>>> Register([FromBody] RegisterUserDto model)
    {
        var result = await _authService.Register(model);
        return StatusCode(result.StatusCode, result);
    }
```

The validation is not working for this authentication method shown here.

This works for other models (Sales, Products etc) in the sale project.

I suppose the issue is from the AuthService (Register) or automapper.

What could be wrong and how do I correct this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Does it throw an exception? Does it always pass validation even when it should fail? Does it always fail validation when it should pass?

Comment: Check if your validator is discovered by fluentvalidation.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson - All the validation fails. For example,  NotNull, Email etc